# SQL: Is it advised to filter table with 'select ... where' before join?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Which of those two variants is more *advised* in general SQL practice:

Lets consider table A with columns: 1,2,3 and table B with columns 3,4. Filtering table with select first:

```
select col2,col4 from 
  (select col1,col2 from tabA 
     where tabA.col3='sth') as t
  join tabB using (col2);
```

or using plain join?:

```
select col2,col4 from tabA 
  join tabB using(col2)
  where col3='sth';
```

We can assume `where` clause matches 1 row. Tables are of similar size. Does Oracle planner deal with such joins properly ot it's gonna create huge joined table and then filter it?

Comment: SQL isn't an imperative language, it's a declarative language. You declare what the problem is, then the DBMS decides how to solve it.  As both queries describe the same problem the DBMS would generate the Exact same explain plan for solving it. So, in this case, the difference is one of style only. I would suggest that the first style adds to much syntactic sugar with very little gained in readability or maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version is an excellent way of writing the query, with the minor exceptions that `col4` and `col3` are not qualified:

```
select col2, col4
from tabA a join
     tabB b
     using (col2)
where a.col3 = 'sth';
```

Just for the record, this is not a *natural join*.  That is a separate construct in SQL -- and rather abominable.

In my experience, Oracle has a good query optimizer.  It will know how to optimize the query for the given conditions.  The subquery should make *no difference whatsoever* to the query plan.  Oracle is not going to filter before the `join`, unless that is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Test it yourself on the real tables using explain plans to learn how many rows are evaluated. I don't believe it is possible to know which would be better, or if there would be any difference. The available indexes make a difference to the optimizer's choice of approach for example.

Regarding your 2 examples I don't like "natural join" syntax ("using") so the first option below is I believe the more common approach (where clause refers directly to the "from table"):

```
select a.col2,b.col4 
from tabA a
inner join tabB b on a.col2 = b.col2
where a.col3='sth'
;
```

but you could also try a join condition like this:

```
select b.col2,b.col4 
from tabB b
inner join tabA a on b.col2 = a.col2 and a.col3='sth'
;
```

note this reverses the table relationship.

Comment: The second query would still have worked without reversing the order.

Comment: @ MatBailie that is true, and while it should make no difference to outcome it might in practice .. that is what I was trying to convey (very badly)

Answer (score 1):

The only time an inner filter will perform better than an outer filter is in (usually complex) cases where the query optimizer chooses a different query plan for one query versus the other.

[Think of it in the same way as a query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/hintsref.htm) `hint`

By reorganizing the query you can influence the query plan without explicitly doing so with a `hint`

As far as which is more advised, whichever is easiest to read is usually best.  Even if one performs better than the other because of where you put your filter, you should instead focus on having the correct indexes to ensure good performance.